# Caching at repository layer in Asp.net application using Caching Application Block

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching, enterprise-library

In one of my webapplication, I am trying to cache some reference entities so as to reduce database hits. I am using Caching application block to implement the caching. I am new to it, and I am not sure about its implementation. I have written a sample repository to utilize it.
I want all of you to please have a look and comment on it.

```
public class StatusRepository
    {
        ICacheManager statusCahce = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(); //I am not sure whether I should initilise statusCache object here.

     public StatusEntity Get(byte statusId)
        {
            StatusCollection statusCollection = (StatusCollection)statusCahce.GetData("Statuses");
            if (statusCollection != null)
            {
                return (StatusEntity)statusCollection.StatusList.First(p=>p.StatusId==statusId);
            }
            else
            {
               // HIT Database to get the entity
            }
        }
       public StatusCollection GetStatusList()
        {
            StatusCollection statusCollection = (StatusCollection)statusCahce.GetData("Statuses");
            SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper(true);
            if (statusCollection != null) //We have it in cache
            {
                return statusCollection;
            }
            else //Hit Database
            {

                     //Hit Database to get the StatusCollection and add that           collection to cache       

                    statusCahce.Add("Statuses", statusCollection);
                    return statusCollection;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know, how can I improve it.

Please also let me know, How much data can we have in cache.

Comment: Accoording to MSDN CacheFactory is not longer in use. Why don't you describe what you really want to achieve so people can suggest alternative technologies or methodologies.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [**this**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) might be of use?